# Values are not posted in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The values of textfield which are not posted in postgresql database.

Below are the source code of 'sample' method in controller

```
def sample
  title = params[:title]
  sample=Sample.new(title)
  sample.save()
end`
```

I have also created the sample.haml in views

sample.haml

```
= form_for :sample, url: sample_path do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :title
    %br/
    = f.text_field :title

  %p
    = f.submit
```

I have also created the migration file which are name as 20161129160810_create_sample.

```
  class CreateSample < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :samples do |t|
        t.string :title
        t.timestamps
        end
        end
```

The problem is when we give the 'title' value and click the submit button,The 'id' value which are stored in sample table but the 'title' value show an empty in the table.

Can you please me for these problem?

Below is the snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Have you added title  to the permitted params in the controller? If you post all the controller code it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect `params[:title]` in the `sample` method, you probably see an empty value. That is because all form values are posted in `params[:sample]`.